# What prepositions are used for communications in social networks?

Tags: preposition

What preposition do you use to say something like

> "I will talk to you **on** skype/facebook/whatsapp."

I made a sentence like this, "Ich werde mit dir reden per whatsapp." Is that correct? If not then how would you correctly say this?

Comment: jemandem **in** or **über** WhatsApp, Facebook eine Nachricht schreiben; aber **bei** Twitter, Facebook etwas posten bzw. schreiben

Answer (score 6):

There are different ways depending a bit on the medium.

For WhatsApp you got it right using "*per*", which is like "via WhatsApp":

> Ich schreibe Dir per WhatsApp.
>   Wir schreiben uns per WhatsApp.

---

When it comes to SMS - as discussed in the comments, you can use either:

> Ich melde mich per SMS bei Dir.

Or more commonly:

> Ich schreibe/schicke Dir eine SMS.
>   Ich simse Dir.

Where the latter is really colloquial and I wouldn't encourage to use it.

---

For a Skype chat you can also use:

> Ich schreibe Dir per Skype.

For a Skype call you can use a verbalization, like in "Google it":

> Wir skypen.

---

For all others "*auf*" (I would suggest using this one) or "*bei*" (not so common) are good choices:

> Ich folge Dir auf(/bei) Twitter.

which means "I follow you on Twitter".

> Ich werde Dir auf/über Facebook schreiben.

Because in this cases you're referring to the platform and not the service.

Comment: At least to my ears „Ich werde mit Dir per soundso schreiben“ is wrong, even though it would be fine with „reden“. I'd suggest „Wir schreiben uns per soundso.“

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Yeah, that bothered me too while answering. I adopted it from the OP. But now as you feel that way too, I've updated the answer. It's a bit vague though, what the OP wants to express.

Comment: Is what I explained I wanna express vague? Well, it's like I posted something on facebook and one of my friends asked Was passiert? I didn't wanna talk about the details of the issue on that public facebook status so I wanted to tell her "I will talk to you about it on whatsapp." Thank you so much for your comment by the way :)

Comment: @Takkat I can see the SMS part - I edited the answer. Regarding "folgen": I would always use "auf", but it seems that "bei" is also common. Take a look at those search results: ["ich folge bei twitter"](https://www.google.de/#q=%22ich+folge+bei+twitter%22) and ["ich folge auf twitter"](https://www.google.de/#q=%22ich+folge+auf+twitter%22)

Comment: @louise Your explanation made the context much clearer. In this case I would simply say: "Ich schreib Dir per WhatsApp." or "Lass uns das über WhatsApp klären.".

Comment: I think "per" would be a great choice, but I don't think I've heard it. Most seem to use "bei" or "auf" in my peer group.

Comment: even if I agree that it should be "per" or "via", we often use "in" in spoken language - "ich schreibe Dir in (der Anwedung?) Facebook"..

Answer (score 1):

I think the good preposition used is *auf*:

> auf skype , auf twitter , auf whatsapp

Comment: "auf Whatsapp"?

Answer (score 1):

## It is ***per***, or ***via***.

***in*** and ***auf*** are used in this context, too.

> Bist du **per** Skype erreichbar?
>
> Lass uns das **via** Skype regeln.

---

Not so often

> Hast du meine Nachricht **in** Skype gesehen?

---

Used in connection with websites

> Ich habe dir was **auf** Facebook geschrieben.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that "per" and "via" are probably the most accurate choices but I don't hear them often. In my peer group at least, these are common:

> Ich schreibe/folge dir **bei** Facebook
>
> Ich schreibe/folge dir **auf** Twitter.

For chats (that are no social networks), there's also:

> Ich schreibe dir **im** ICQ.
> <sup>Basically, "in" plus the dativ.</sup>

Comment: Well, I've never heard "im" ICQ but only "in" ICQ. Same applies to other messengers. – The first part of your answer, however, has already be given in the last section of [insertusernamehere's answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/8075/1224).